# How to pass a file pointer to a different function

Tags: file, go

If I have created a file in my `main()` function:

```
output, err := os.Create("D:\\output.txt")
```

And I want everything that another function in the program prints, to be put in that file using:

```
output.WriteString(str)
```

How could I pass a pointer to that file so that function could write to it?
Also, is there any other way I should use to write a string to a file, or `WriteString` is succicient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have your function take a pointer as a parameter using the `*` type modifier, and just pass your file object as-is since os.Create already returns a pointer:

```
func WriteStringToFile(f *os.File) {
    n, err := f.WriteString("foobar")
}

// ..

output, err := os.Create("D:\\output.txt")
WriteStringToFile(output)
```

Also, please note that it is good practice not to ignore errors.

To write strings into a file can be done in a few different ways, especially if you want to avoid using the `os.File` object directly, and only use the io.Writer interface. For example:

```
fmt.Fprint(output, "foo bar")
```

Comment: okay thanks! i actually didn't even need to use the ampersand since os.Create already returns the address of that variable. Also, do you know how i could "print" a new line to a file? when i use "\n" it works great in the console but doesn't work at all when i output it as a string to a .txt file

Comment: Good that you actually caught the mistake in both answers by yourself :) It was totally done on purpose, haha. Just kidding, I'm going to fix this. Also, on Windows, if you want your file to look correctly in notepad, you need to use "\r\n" instead of just "\n"

Answer (score 2):

Simply define a function that can take `*File` pointer as argument:

```
func Write(output *os.File) {
 (...)
}

Write(&output) //call function.
```

}

Also you may want to ensure that file is closed in the end using:

```
defer output.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks but i had to use *os,File as mentioned below!

Comment: Right! :) I've corrected my answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Using an interface such as `io.Writer` is the way to go. Many types in Go fulfill the `io.Writer` just by having a `Write` method. `os.File` is one of those types.